# Why can I not call the interface method?

Tags: java, android, delegates

Disclaimer: I'm coming from Swift so my idea on how delegation works is biased.

I have an interface defined:

```
public interface IChatButtonResponse {
    void chat(ListingEntry listingEntry, String initialUserText);
}
```

My class has a local reference to it that is saved when instantiated:

```
public class ListingAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private IChatButtonResponse delegate;

    public ListingAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListingEntry> listingEntries, IChatButtonResponse delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
```

When I try to call the delegate in response to a button tap, I get a compilation error:

```
chatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    delegate.chat(listingEntry, null);  // Cannot resolve symbol 'chat'
});
```

Why can it not be resolved? I tried to make the method declaration in the interface public but that didn't change anything. (I would have been surprised if it did)

EDIT:
My usage of the interface in the same package:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IChatButtonResponse {
```

.
.
.

```
@Override
void chat(ListingEntry listingEntry, String initialUserText) {

}
```

I am getting a compilation error here: `'chat(ListingEntry, String)' in ...sample.app.MainActivity' clashes with 'chat(ListingEntry, String) in ...sample.app.IChatButtonResponse'; attempting to assign weaker access privileges ('package-private'); was 'public'`

Tried making the implementation method public with no change.

Comment: Do you have an implementation of that interface method in another class?

Comment: My guess is that the `IChatButtonResponse` that's the type of `delegate` is a different type to your interface... otherwise that looks like it should work.

Comment: Is the IChatButtonResponse package private?

Comment: Question edited to show interface adherence

Comment: The code looks ok, do you have two classes with same name `IChatButtonResponse` in different packages, if yes then are you importing the right one in your `ListingAdapter`?

Comment: @shantanu all references to IChatButtonResponse are shown above.

Comment: Re, "I am getting a compilation error here..." The `chat` method in your _implementation_ must be `public:`.

Comment: @shantanu Tried that and it didn't help

Comment: in which class does chatButton.setOnClickListener is implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the original error in question, the clue was found on another error I hadn't noticed earlier on the chatButton.setOnClickListener.

The OnClickListener method onClick must be overridden like this:

```
chatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String referenceID = listingEntry.referenceID;
        delegate.chat(listingEntry,null);
    }
 });
```

This fixes the resolution error at the call site.